# Create a developer fork of non-Github repository

Tags: git

I'd like to create a developer fork (not checkout) of a **non**-Github repository.  The setup:

- `Main` repository is on machine X in /export/git/foo.git
- `Main` repository has many branches.
- New bare repository created in /home/me/fork.git on machine X.
- Want to bring some but not all branches from `Main` repository into new repository.  Would like to bring over branch histories into new repository.
- Want to be able to easily bring new commits from `Main` into the new repository.

Bonus points for spelling out how to push commits from the new repository back to `Main` without using patches.

I searched this site and the Internet but did not see this use case solved.  What are the git commands needed to do the above?

Machine X is a Linux box.

Comment: So the only thing different from a normal local checkout of foo.git is that some of the branches are not in your checkout?

Comment: I don't want to just do a checkout.  I need another repo.

Comment: It's not clear what "just a checkout" means with Git. It sounds like you want a regular (possibly bare) repository clone. Well, not quite since you don't need all branches but it's not obvious that it's worthwhile to care about that.

Comment: I edited the question to hopefully make it clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the steps:

1. Clone a new local repo of the remote repo you wish to fork:

   `git clone [source url] source_repo`
2. Change into the just created directory (source_repo).
3. For every branch you wish to fork, do:

   `git branch --track [branch name]`
4. Add the new remote repository:

   `git remote add [dest repo name] [dest repo url]`
5. Now push the branches up to the forked repository:

   `git push --all [dest repo name]`

Answer derived from [this](http://blog.dynamic50.com/2009/11/26/moving-your-git-repos-and-all-branches-to-a-new-remote-repository/).